# Sails.js - How include license notice in production.min.js?

Tags: sails.js

I use many dependencies in my web project, for example [Sigma.js](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js) under MIT license. I want to add the [notice](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/LICENSE.txt) to the production.min.js file created by the server in production mode. But all comments are deleted by the minimisation. What can I do to add this notice ? There is a configuration of Grunt to do that ?

Comment: how about create a file with just the license header you want, call it license.txt, then add a step after minimizing, where you copy the license.txt to a new file, and append the minimized js file to it. rinse repeat with each file you have.

Comment: @Xerion I'm looking for a automatic method to concatenate the license.txt and the minimized file of JavaScript. There may be a configuration file in `/task/` folder in a sails project, for solving this problem.